# Combination of radio and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML form, where I use "radio" buttons, but I would like them to work as if they were a combination of radio and checkbox: one option is possible to be checked but also there is a possibilty to unselect an option.

My form is here:

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="radio" name="transport" value="transport1">
<input type="radio" name="transport" value="transport2">
<input type="radio" name="transport" value="transport3">
</form>
```

I found nice function to do it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
(function ($) {
$.fn.uncheckableRadio = function () {

    return this.each(function () {
        var radio = this;
            $('label[for="' + radio.id + '"]').add(radio).mousedown(function () {
                $(radio).data('wasChecked', radio.checked);
            });

            $('label[for="' + radio.id + '"]').add(radio).click(function () {
                if ($(radio).data('wasChecked'))
                    radio.checked = false;
            });
       });
};
})(jQuery);

$('input[type=radio]').uncheckableRadio();
});

</script>
```

But this function harms my different function , which is used to count price from form inputs (when I select radio buton price is added correctly, but when I deselect buton it doesn't change):

```
function count_price()
        {
        var price=0;

        if (document.forms["myform"].transport[0].checked) {price+=100;}
        if (document.forms["myform"].transport[1].checked) {price+=50;}
        if (document.forms["myform"].transport[2].checked) {price+=200;}    
        }

        document.all["counted_price"].innerHTML=price;
        };
```

Without using this "uncheckableRadio" function my count_price function works well.

Comment: When you say "possibility to unselect an option", do you mean you want the ability to have no options selected at all? Why not just have an additional radio button labelled "no transport"? That way you won't need any script at all.

Comment: I do need to have this deselection posibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you call count_price() first and then uncheckableRadio().
Try to call count_price() after `radio.checked = false;` to update the price.

```
$('label[for="' + radio.id + '"]').add(radio).click(function () {
    if ($(radio).data('wasChecked'))
        radio.checked = false;
    count_price();
});
```

Further I support Simbas comment. Just add another button and stop using the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can use data-checked attribute to save checked / unchecked state of radio button and change its `checked` attribute accordingly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name=myform] input[type=radio][name=transport]').click(function(){
        var checked = $(this).data('checked') || false;
         $(this).data('checked', !checked);
        $(this).attr('checked', !checked);
        $('form[name=myform] input[type=radio][name=transport]').not(this).data('checked', false);
    });
});
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b2nd7m7y/10/)**

Comment: Works well regarding selection/deselection, but still harms count_price function (adds correctly, but after deselection price is not changing).

Comment: You have one extra `}` after calculating price and before setting it to `document.all["counted_price"].innerHTML=price;` hence it is causing  problem. Remove it , check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b2nd7m7y/7/)

Comment: Works well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

https://jsfiddle.net/93fy9dwo/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        this.checked = true;
    });
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        this.checked = false;
    });
});
```